# Differentiation between the namespace, path, mountpoint, etc

Tags: vaultsharp

The Hashicorp documentation leaves a lot to be desired when it comes to implementing a solution using .Net and the VaultSharp documentation isn't as comprehensive enough to cover the multitude of scenarios.

We have our Vault setup with a namespace, "egw". We have a KV Secrets Engine enabled with a name of "Expr". We have secrets listed at 3 different paths: "Trans", "Set" and "Serv".

We are unsure how to actually read these secrets as it is UNCLEAR the differentiation between the namespace, path, mountpoint, etc.

The documentation's all over the place and not clear to us on any of these terms and the sample apps are useless to us due to the wrong auth methods.

We are using LDAP Auth Method so we can login to our server without issues, it's just getting to the secrets that we're having issues with.

Can someone, please, explain to us how to read these secrets using VaultSharp?

Update:
We currently do NOT have roles created or assigned.

Can someone, please, help me to understand why this code fails to
either list the paths OR fetch the secrets? Am I doing something
incorrectly or just not understanding how it needs to be done?

```
IAuthMethodInfo authMethod = new LDAPAuthMethodInfo(_settings.LDAPUserName, _settings.LDAPPassword);
var vaultClientSettings = new VaultClientSettings(_settings.Address, authMethod);

IVaultClient vaultClient = new VaultClient(vaultClientSettings);

Secret<ListInfo> secret = await vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V2.ReadSecretPathsAsync("egw/Expr/data/");
ListInfo paths = secret.Data;

Secret<SecretData>? kv2Secret = await vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V2.ReadSecretAsync(path: "Expr/data/Trans", mountPoint:"egw/");
Dictionary<string, object> dataDictionary = kv2Secret.Data.Data;
```

This is the error message and StackTrace I am getting:

```
Message: 
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

  Stack Trace: 
    JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
    JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent()
    JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
    JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
    JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
    JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
    Polymath.MakeRequestAsync[TResponse](String resourcePath, HttpMethod httpMethod, Object requestData, IDictionary`2 headers, Boolean rawResponse, Action`1 postResponseAction)
    Polymath.MakeVaultApiRequest[TResponse](String resourcePath, HttpMethod httpMethod, Object requestData, Boolean rawResponse, Action`1 postResponseAction, String wrapTimeToLive, Boolean unauthenticated)
    LDAPAuthMethodLoginProvider.GetVaultTokenAsync()
    Polymath.MakeVaultApiRequest[TResponse](String resourcePath, HttpMethod httpMethod, Object requestData, Boolean rawResponse, Action`1 postResponseAction, String wrapTimeToLive, Boolean unauthenticated)
    Polymath.MakeVaultApiRequest[TResponse](String mountPoint, String path, HttpMethod httpMethod, Object requestData, Boolean rawResponse, Action`1 postResponseAction, String wrapTimeToLive, Boolean unauthenticated)
    KeyValueSecretsEngineV2Provider.ReadSecretAsync(String path, Nullable`1 version, String mountPoint, String wrapTimeToLive)
```

Update2:
Found that using LDAP AuthMethod isn't working correctly, not sure if it's the way it's setup on the Vault or what. Began using the Token and was able to read the secrets but when trying to list them, I get *permission denied*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Namespaces provide a way for your Vault service to be fully self-managed](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/enterprise/namespaces).  This is more an administrative detail than a programming detail, and you can *largely* disregard that.  Ultimately, you just need to know what your namespace is called.

[Your secrets engine is where the secrets actually reside, and how they are stored](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets).  For most cases, you're using a KV (key-value) secrets engine, version 2.

The paths you list just describe locations where your secrets reside in your secrets engine.

So with the information you've given:

- Namespace is `egw`
- Secrets engine is KV with name of `Expr`
- Paths exist at `Trans`, `Set`, and `Serv`

...you'd *probably* be referencing it from these paths.  Note that [KV secrets engines store their values at the data/ path](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v2#usage), so you have to include that after you request from the secrets engine.

- `egw/Expr/data/Trans`
- `egw/Expr/data/Set`
- `egw/Expr/data/Serv`

As an access note:  You're *really* going to want to consider [using an AppRole](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/approle) to access these secrets if you're doing machine-to-machine communication.  Doing all of that with LDAP is going to be complex and relies on LDAP *and* Vault being alive versus with AppRoles, which only needs Vault to be alive, and allows for very fine-grained access to secrets.

Comment: Eventually, we're going to be using JWT Authentication, we're using LDAP for dev testing

Comment: So, you're saying that this *should* work and return the Secrets? Secret<Dictionary<string, object>> kv1Secret = vaultClient.V1.Secrets.KeyValue.V1.ReadSecretAsync("egw/Expr/data/Trans").Result;

Comment: I don't speak C# so I can't definitively answer *that* much.  But if you're intending to read things, then that *appears* to be the right path, provided an authenticated client, and some allowances for extra slashes.  One thing to note is that your library *might* not like the extra `/data/ path, whereas other libraries I've dealt with (mostly Python and Java) *do*.  You'll need to experiment here; my goal was to help you disambiguate between everything and make sure you had every component you needed.

Comment: Well, I keep getting this error, no matter what path I set: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: @MB34, I am the creator of VaultSharp. If you're still looking for an answer, can you please open a GH issue on the VaultSharp repo with the latest code snippet? I can assist.

Comment: Got it squared away. Everything's working now